# Как совместить таблицы

Tags: python, pandas, csv, join

Нужно для сайта объединить две таблицы csv с данными

Первая основная. В ней больше строк и столбцов

```
id;links;some;some1;some2;some3
1;https://site.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/phones_puctures/Alcatel-3C-169.png;0;attachment;image/png;0
2;https://site.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/phones_puctures/Alcatel-3C-214.png;0;attachment;image/png;0
3;https://site.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/phones_puctures/Alcatel-3C-269.png;0;attachment;image/png;0
4;https://site.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/phones_puctures/Alcatel-3C-271.jpg;0;attachment;image/jpeg;0
5;https://site.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/phones_puctures/Alcatel-3C-374.png;0;attachment;image/png;0
6;link;0;attachment;image/png;0
7;link;0;attachment;image/png;0
8;link;0;attachment;image/png;0
9;link;0;attachment;image/jpeg;0
10;link;0;attachment;image/png;0
```

Вторая содержит имена(первый столбец), которые мне и нужно получить в первую

```
name;links;eshehu
Alcatel 3c;https://site.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/phones_puctures/Alcatel-3C-214.png;site2/Alcatel 3c-1
Alcatel 3c;https://site.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/phones_puctures/Alcatel-3C-169.png;site2/Alcatel 3c-2
Alcatel 3c;https://site.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/phones_puctures/Alcatel-3C-271.jpg;site2/Alcatel 3c-3
Alcatel 3c;https://site.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/phones_puctures/Alcatel-3C-269.png;site2/Alcatel 3c-4
Alcatel 3c;https://site.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/phones_puctures/Alcatel-3C-374.png;site2/Alcatel 3c-5
Alcatel 4c;https://site.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/phones_puctures/Alcatel-4C-269.png;site2/Alcatel 4c-1
Alcatel 4c;https://site.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/phones_puctures/Alcatel-4C-374.png;site2/Alcatel 4c-2
```

Единственная возможность связать их через столбец links, который совпадает для многих строк.

То есть на выходе мне нужно получить первую таблицу + столбец name по соответствию ссылок.

Я пробовал делать join и merge в pandas, но результатом всегда возвращается первая таблица без изменений.

Вроде такого:

```
photo_full.merge(name_table, left_on='links', right_on='links')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод `.merge()` не изменяет таблицу. Вы не сохранили результат. Сделайте это:

```
photo_full = photo_full.merge(name_table, left_on='links', right_on='links')
```

---

Тест:

```
print(photo_full)
```

> ```
>    id                                              links  some       some1  \
> 0   1  https://site.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/phone...     0  attachment   
> 1   2  https://site.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/phone...     0  attachment   
> 2   3  https://site.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/phone...     0  attachment   
> 3   4  https://site.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/phone...     0  attachment   
> 4   5  https://site.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/phone...     0  attachment   
>
>         some2  some3        name              eshehu  
> 0   image/png      0  Alcatel 3c  site2/Alcatel 3c-2  
> 1   image/png      0  Alcatel 3c  site2/Alcatel 3c-1  
> 2   image/png      0  Alcatel 3c  site2/Alcatel 3c-4  
> 3  image/jpeg      0  Alcatel 3c  site2/Alcatel 3c-3  
> 4   image/png      0  Alcatel 3c  site2/Alcatel 3c-5
> ```

Comment: лол, я полтора часа не мог понять в чём дело...)